# How to take long exposure photos in the daytime?

Tags: long-exposure, canon-600d

On a Canon 600D, what are the best settings for a 4-8sec long exposure in the daytime? I have tried manual and shutter priority modes but photos always come out completely white.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. What do you want to take a photo of that requires such a long exposure during daytime? I assume it's to create some sort of motion blur?

Answer (score 0):

In daylight it is not possible to took such a long pose: the amount of light reaching the sensor is too important: that why your image is "burned" (overexposed full white).

What you could do to reduce the amount of light and incrasse the exposure time without burning the image is

- lower the sensitivity (iso) as down as possible,
- close the diafragm (pass in aperture mode and rise the f-number as much as possible

but in order to really access long poses the only way is to bought a ND filter: that is a gray filter wich will let pass only a part of the light...

Comment: I'd disagree with the recommendation to have the smallest aperture possible - that's going to reduce the sharpness due to diffraction, which for a lot of long exposure applications (waterfalls, etc) is exactly what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer will depend a bit on what you're trying to photograph, but if you're trying to do something like a long exposure shot of a waterfall or the like, in general you'll want:

- Base ISO (i.e. ISO 100 for the 600D)
- Aperture in the "sweet spot" for your lens - probably around f/8 to f/11 or so.
- A [neutral density filter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures) to cut down the amount of light reaching the sensor

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a **neutral-density filter** to allow you to keep the shutter open longer in daylight without letting in so much light that it ruins the picture. There are a few other questions on this topic that you should check out:

- [Is it possible to take a long exposure photograph during daytime?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/is-it-possible-to-take-a-long-exposure-photograph-during-daytime)
- [What are neutral density filters and how do I use them to create long exposures in daylight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures)