# Tips and resources for nightime shots with a mirrorless camera?

Tags: night, mirrorless, samsung

I have a mirrorless digital camera (Samsung NX1000, 20-50mm lens) with which I'm proficient in all manual settings.  I'm on vacation in a month on an island in the Atlantic that is known for low levels of light pollution.  I'm contemplating taking my tripod and doing some long exposures at night.  Is this a worthwhile effort or do I truly need a different lens?  I know I'm not going to get a detail image of the face of the moon but maybe catch the milky way.  Any good resources for beginner night photography for my setup?

Comment: Have you looked at the general questions on the site around low light and astro photography? That you're shooting smaller sensor isn't really going to change any of the basics.

Comment: Where do these general questions exist?

Comment: Use the tag system (see link at top) and the search.

Comment: JoanneC: the Samsung NX cameras use APS-C sensors, they're not micro four-thirds, so the sensor's the same size as a crop dSLR would use.

Comment: @inkista - I shoot with a D800, APS-C is a smaller sensor. :)

Comment: JoanneC: [grin]. Yes, this is very true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of examples of photos of the Milky Way taken with 18-55 kit lenses on APS-C dSLRs, so I don't see why using your 20-50mm on an APS-C mirrorless like the Samsung NX1000 should be an issue.  Astrophotography is more about long exposure technique.

Where you *might* be more limited than with a dSLR is that from the specs it looks like the NX1000's bulb mode maxes out at 4 minutes.  But 4 minutes is much longer than you would need if you were to follow [the Rule of 600](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30263/what-is-the-rule-of-600-in-astrophotography) to avoid star trails, and you can always [stack images](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23104/what-is-image-stacking-as-it-relates-to-astrophotography).

See also [How do I capture the milky way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37261/how-do-i-capture-the-milky-way)
and the [[astrophotography] tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography).